# Converting SQL into Relational Algebra - what to do next?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I'm trying to convert an SQL command into relational algebra. The biggiest problem is that there is a "NOT IN" SQL statement which is not in relational algebra.

My query did this:

Select employee id, last name and training_id (from training) from employees, who have a training this quartal but do not have all prerequisites for this training - so they did not complete prerequisity training never.

If result ends with X, it means that it was not completed successfuly.

TABLES:

```
employee(employee_id, first_name, last_name)
training(training_id, quartal, year, name)
enrollment(employee_id, training_id, quartal, year, result)
prerequisity(training_id, prerequisity_id)
```

My SQL query:

```
select e.employee_id, lastname, training_id from employee as e NATURAL JOIN enrollment NATURAL JOIN training NATURAL JOIN prerequisity WHERE quartal = 'first' and year = '2016'  and training_id NOT IN (select e.training_id from enrollment as e NATURAL JOIN employee as ee where e.employee_id=ee.employee_id and result not like '%X' and result is not NULL)
```

This is probably correct SQL so now I'm going to convert it into relational algebra:

```
PROJECT[employee_id,lastname, training_id](SELECT[quartal='first',year='2016'](employee@enrollment@training@prerequisity)) # here is the problem
```

How to simulate "NOT IN" command in RA?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the use of  `Set Difference (−)`

The result of set difference operation is tuples, which are present in one relation but are not in the second relation.

```
PROJECT[employee_id,lastname, training_id](SELECT[quartal='first',year='2016']
    (employee@enrollment@training@prerequisity))  - (PROJECT training_id ....
```